# Optimizing PyroCMS code for Keywords

Tags: codeigniter, optimization, module, keyword, pyrocms

I built this method following the the tagged() method from blog module

```
public function genres($genre = null)
{
    $this->db->order_by('name', 'ASC');
    $result = $this->db->get('keywords');
    $genres = $result->result();

    if($genre)
    {
        $this->load->model('genres_m');
        // decode encoded cyrillic characters
        $genre = rawurldecode($genre) OR redirect('generos');

        $time[] = time();
        // Count total blog posts and work out how many pages exist
        $pagination = create_pagination(lang('ebooks:routes:genres') . '/' . $genre, $this->genres_m->count_genres_by($genre, array('entry_active' => 1)), NULL, 4);

        $time[] = time();
        // Get the current page of blog posts
        $books = $this->genres_m
            ->limit($pagination['per_page'])
            ->order_by('info_title', 'ASC')
            ->get_genres_by($genre, array('entry_active' => 1));

        $time[] = time();
        foreach ($books AS &$book)
        {
            $book->books_info_genre = Keywords::get($book->books_info_genre, 'blog/tagged');
            $book->url = site_url(lang('ebooks:routes:ebook') . '/' . $book->info_title . '/' . $book->id);
        }

        $time[] = time();
        // Set meta description based on post titles
        //$meta = $this->_posts_metadata($books);

        $name = str_replace('-', ' ', $genre);

        // Build the page
        $this->template
            ->title($this->_template_title(lang('ebooks:of').' '.$name))
            ->set_metadata('description', $this->_template_title(lang('ebooks:of').' '.$name))
            ->set_metadata('keywords', $this->_template_title(lang('ebooks:of').' '.$name))
            ->set('genres', $genres)
            ->set('books', $books)
            ->set('genre', $genre)
            ->set('time', $time)
            ->set('pagination', $pagination)
            ->build('genres-list');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->template->title($this->_template_title(lang('ebooks:genres_by')))
            ->set_metadata('description', $this->_template_title(lang('ebooks:genres_by')))
            ->set_metadata('keywords', $this->_template_title(lang('ebooks:genres_by')))
            ->set('genres', $genres)
            ->build('genres-list');
    }
}
```

And, this is the model:

```
public function count_genres_by($genre, $params)
{
    return $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('downloads_books_book_info')
        ->join('keywords_applied', 'keywords_applied.hash = downloads_books_book_info.books_info_genre')
        ->join('keywords', 'keywords.id = keywords_applied.keyword_id')
        ->where('keywords.name', str_replace('-', ' ', $genre))
        ->where($params)
        ->count_all_results();
}

    public function get_genres_by($genre, $params)
{
    return $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('downloads_books_book_info')
        ->join('keywords_applied', 'keywords_applied.hash = downloads_books_book_info.books_info_genre')
        ->join('keywords', 'keywords.id = keywords_applied.keyword_id')
        ->where('keywords.name', str_replace('-', ' ', $genre))
        ->where($params)
        ->get()
        ->result();
}
```

As you can see in the first part of code, I got the time() four times, giving the delays:

18:49 - 19:03 - 19:41 - 19:41

I have a DB with about 5K entries. How can I optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2.2.0-beta1 and take advantage of the Search system, which will store all keywords as text and knock out a few joins for your queries.

Otherwise you can build your own index table using blog events, which will store keywords next to blog id's.

The main problem is that your are running an SQL query on EVERY single returned item, whilst it would be quicker to work out all the keywords in one go. Even a SQL sub-query would be slightly quicker.

Comment: Thanks. I have to try the new Search system.